# Choice of a skeleton

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Suppose we are in presence of a strong enough axiom of choice (e.g., choice for conglomerates). I know that any category has a skeleton, but I would like to know if I can choose a skeleton which contains some distinguished objects.

Let $C$ be a category and suppose that I have a distinguished class $D$ of pairwise non-isomorphic objects of $C$. Can I "complete" $D$ to a skeleton of $C$?

If the above question has a positive answer, suppose I have another class $D'$ of pairwise non-isomorphic objects in $C$ (which has trivial intersection with $D$) such that any object of $D'$ is isomorphic exactly to one object of $D$ and this exhausts all of $D$. Also, for any object $X$ in $D'$ we have a distinguished isomorphism $\phi_X$ between $X$ to the unique object in $D$ isomorphic to $X$.

Can I find a skeleton $S$ of $C$ and an equivalence of categories $F:C\to S$ such that $F(\phi_X)$ is an identity for all $X\in D'$?

Comment: I don't see a reason why not.

Comment: Of course, me neither... this is why I am asking here...

Comment: I don't quite know what a skeleton is, but I'm working under the assumption that it's a class of objects which are pairwise non-isomorphic, and every object is isomorphic to one of them?

Comment: Not just that. It is a full subcategory where any two isomorphic objects are equal. The part which is not clear to me is especially the second part of the question, the existence of that specific functor

Comment: I get confused by categorical terminology. So I'm not quite sure that I understand the last part. But I don't see any issues with that either. I suppose it's better to just wait for someone who can read this question and make sense of it without guessing the definitions. :-)

Comment: OK, thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Actually, in my mind, a skeleton is not just a full subcategory but also equipped with a quasi-inverse to the inclusion. At any rate, all you need is a sufficiently strong axiom of choice (and the law of excluded middle).